# BeautifulSoup4: FileNotFoundError for Opening URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup4 to scrape a site.  Here's a condensed version of what I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getTeamRoster(teamURL):
     soup = BeautifulSoup(open(teamURL))

def main():
     getTeamRoster("http://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/Team_Information.asp?id=11325")
```

I've pulled up the page and it loads properly in my browser (Chrome).  For some reason, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SquashScraper.py", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  File "SquashScraper.py", line 58, in main
    getTeamRoster("http://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/Team_Information.asp?id=11325")
  File "SquashScraper.py", line 21, in getTeamRoster
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(teamURL))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/Team_Information.asp?id=11325'
```

Any idea what may be happening?

I've looked at other people's BeautifulSoup4 code and thought what I did was the idiomatic way of accessing a page's HTML.

Thanks,
bclayman

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup mentions in the description that it is a library for *parsing*, not a library that actually fetches the HTML from a remote website. For that, you will need another library like `urllib` (specifically the function `urlopen` and then `read` from the object that it returns).

As for why you are getting the Python error, `open` is designed for opening files, not for HTML retrieval. If you were to open a local file that contains HTML, your code would work. However, because you have a URL as an argument, open is actually looking for a file on *your* system with that name. Because that file does not exist, it raises an error.

Answer (score 0):

The `open` is looking for a local file. You want to first save the HTML of the page you're trying to load into a string, then use BeautifulSoup. Condensed into its essentials, given your naming:

```
import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen(teamURL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```